# Rule of exponents -- why does $2^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It's been a long time since high school, and I guess I forgot my rules of exponents.  I did a web search for this rule but I could not find a rule that helps me explain this case:

$ 2^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1} $

Which rule of exponents is this?

Comment: $\underbrace{2^n+2^n}_2=2\cdot 2^n=2^{n+1}$

Comment: I don't understand the step $ 2 \cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1} $

Comment: $a^ua^v=\underbrace{a\cdots a}_u\cdot\underbrace{a\cdots a}_v=\underbrace{a\cdots\cdots a}_{u+v}=a^{u+v}$

Comment: Oh, tricky!  Thank you.

Comment: Because one and one equals two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2^n + 2^n = 2^n(1+1) = 2^n(2) = 2^{n+1}$

Answer (score 3):

If you realise that there are $2$ of $2^n$, then we have
$$2^1\times2^n$$
If we are multiplying  $2$ by itself **n** times and then multiplying the result by another $2$, we get $2$ multiplied by itself **n+1** times, which is $$2^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$2^{N} + 2^{N} = 2^{N}(1+1) = 2^{N}(2) = 2^{N+1}.$

Just a little trickery with the distributive law.